# Excel sheet properties window comes up blank

Tags: excel, properties, vba

I'm trying to access the Properties window for an Excel (2007, in this case) worksheet, using the Properties button on the Developer tab, as described [here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/01/25/worksheet-properties-via-a-menu/). The reason I want to get at the Properties window is to set properties such as the object's name, for use in VBA scripts that address it.

The Properties window comes up, but it's blank, with no identification of the object I'm looking at at the top, and no properties listed. Why is this, and how do I get around it?

Comment: my +1 for future cases)

Comment: This question is about a tool used during development of Excel-VBA scripts. If Excel-VBA is on-topic, so should this question.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that the reason for this was that I had the associated VBA project password-protected. When I opened up the VBA project and entered the password when prompted, the Properties window started working again.